# Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, external-files, online

I have tried

```
\includegraphics{http://www.site.com/path/to/figure.png}
```

But this returns the error

> ```
> ERROR: Package pdftex.def Error: File
> `http://www.website.com/path/to/figure.png'
> not found.
> ```

Are there other options?

Comment: ConTeXt supports this natively. `\externalfigure[http://www.site.com/path/to/figure.png]` just works. Behind the scenes, ConTeXt downloads the file to the luatex cache once, and from then on just reuses the figure.

Comment: do you want to add this as an answer? That way, I can select it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

you could use `\write18` and a curl or wget script to grab the image from the web and download it to your directory.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % includegraphics command is implemented here
\begin{document}

\write18{wget http://www.some-site.com/path/to/image.png}
\includegraphics{image.png}

\end{document}
```

note however, that recent versions of miktex and texlive come with restricted versions of \write18, and it some cases you must pass an option to latex to enable it, as in:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

Comment: could you please provide example code in your answer? I did not realize that it was possible to use bash code within latex, although I do use Sweave so I can understand the principle.

Comment: nice! I guess that this underscores the point that I only need to download the image once in any case. But this approach seems like it would help with portability.

Comment: `\IfFileExists{image.png}{}{\write18{...}}` would help with the only-downloading-once problem.

Comment: Could this be done programmatically somehow, maybe with a \renewcommand such that includegraphics can just take the url as an argument?

Answer (score 44):

Short answer: no. You will need to download the image and use it locally if you want to include it in your document. pdfTeX and XeTeX do not include the necessary code to grab an image from an arbitrary location.

Of course, you can link to an image at at remote location. You can make use of the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to include a suitable link. You might do this using a bit of text:

```
\href{http://somewhere.com/someplace/some.jpg}{picture here}
```

or by downloading a local copy and then pointing to the online version

```
\href{http://somewhere.com/someplace/some.jpg}{\incudegraphics{some.jpg}}
```

I note from the comments that LuaTeX does include the necessary library to download a copy of an image itself. That would make inclusion possible directly, but I don't know of a pre-build solution for LuaLaTeX. I guess that would be a separate answer in any case.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, it seems to me that your short answer contradicts your second answer. And, could you please provide an example of how can I use hyperref to do this?

Comment: @David: I've added a bit more detail

Comment: I'm trying this kind of reference, but it seems to fail - has the relevant functionality been removed? (I'm getting a "some.jpg is missing" error)

Answer (score 7):

(Copying from the comments section)

ConTeXt supports this natively:

http://wiki.contextgarden.net/What_is_ConTeXt

The following:

```
\externalfigure[http://www.site.com/path/to/figure.png]
```

just works. Behind the scenes, ConTeXt downloads the file to the luatex cache once, and from then on just reuses the figure.

---

My additional notes:

- If you have MacTeX, you don't need to do any extra installation. Just
  change the typesetting option inside your TeX editor.
- I couldn't get
  this to work in TeXShop, but it works fine in TeXWorks. Also, I had
  to use `ConTeXt (LuaTeX)`. It didn't work when I tried `ConTeXt
  (pdfTeX)`.

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question which is about embedding a remote image file using LaTeX.

Comment: But it does solve what the user is trying to do, which he explicitly said he is happy to mark as correct. And I started using ConTeXt as a result of what the comment said. Please read up on the XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

I just added this option in the v2.3 of [`robust-externalize`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/master/doc/robust-externalize.pdf) (if CTAN does not come with it by default, you can just [download the .sty file](https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/) at the root of your project):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\robExtConfigure{enable fallback to manual mode} % Optional, but prints instructions if shell-escape is disabled instead of giving a compilation error.

\begin{document}

Here is a cat downloaded online: \includegraphicsWeb[width=3cm]{http://placekitten.com/400/303}. 

\end{document}
```

Make sure to compile the first time with `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex` (or manually run the generated bash script if you do not want to enable shell escape), once the image is downloaded you do not need shell escape anymore (since the image is cached in the `robustExternalize` folder). Note that you can remove all cached pictures which are not used anymore by running `python robExt-remove-old-figures.py`.

By default, it uses `wget` in linux and `curl` in windows (installed by default starting from Windows 10 I think), but this can easily be customized. Cf documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the SE bot revived this question after 13 years! I notice that none of the previous answers and comments mentions something vital: possible copyright infringement.

Even though (depending on compiler, recency of software, platform, etc.) it
is sometimes possible to pull a web image into the document, and even though it is almost always possible to place a *locally downloaded* image in the document, that image is likely to be the copyrighted work of someone else. The copyright holder may or may not (usually not) grant a license for usage. Just because you can *see* it freely, does not mean that you can *use* it, free or not.

Even if the image does not have a copyright notice as its caption, and even if the web page says nothing, does *not* mean that it is free. You should look through the web site, to see if there is anything that specifically allows you do download and use any content (such as images). Unless there is an explicit declaration of copyright by someone who can be identified, and that copyright holder grants you explicit license to use it for your purpose, then do not use it.

You may still provide a hyperlink, because this does not involve copying the content. But be aware that links change. What's to stop some prankster from
posting an equation, then later changing that image to something naughty?