# Inserting an image using an http URL

Tags: graphics, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document)

I am trying to re-use the same `pandoc/markdown` source file to generate both HTML and LaTeX source and PDF.

Is it possible to insert an image in a .tex file using an `http` URL?

For example, using `http://example.com/myimage.png` as the image location for `\includegraphics` via some package?

Thank you.

Comment: Oops! My apologies. It looks like this topic has already been discussed at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document

Comment: It has, but you are specifically asking for an `\includegraphics` extension to support this. The task to turn the code of the other answer it into an package that extends the `\includegraphics` interface is still open :-)