# Programmatically load an image from LyX

Tags: lyx, shell-escape

Following the accepted answer to this question: [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document)

I am trying to insert the following code to a trivial LyX document:

```
\write18{wget "http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/img/logo.png" -O "/home/erelsgl/logo.png"}
```

I export the document to PS, but the file is not downloaded, and I get no error message (the trivial LyX document is indeed shown in PS).

How can I make LyX run the command?

I saw that there is a "shell-escape" argument that should be passed to the tex file processor, but how do I access it from LyX?

Comment: Is is really worth downloading the image using LaTeX instead of just downloading it by hand? Does all operating systems even have `wget`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did add the `\write18` in an ERT, or the preamble?

I think you add the `--shell-escape` flag in Tools --> Preferences -->  File Handling --> Converters. If you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, find the entry in the list called **LaTeX (pdfLaTeX) -> PDF (pdflatex)**. Add `--shell-escape` in the Converter field, between `pdflatex` and `$$i`:

[image: preferences window]

Comment: Sorry for the side question, but can a new converter be created so that it could specifically use `-shell-escape`? With this method two `LaTeX->PDF` converters can be used with ease dealing with graphics or external programs such as `gnuplot`.

Comment: @AndreaL. Take a look at Help --> Customization, section 3.3 Converters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but specifically, it says *"...quindi i format devono avere nomi differenti. Date un’occhiata e poi createne dei vostri!"*, or "...therefore format files must have different names. Take a look and then create some of yours". The section is unexpanded, and so it gives only the fact that the button `Add` *exists*, not its action (as you can see is *disabled* in your picture).

Comment: @AndreaL. Sorry, I didn't really read that carefully, but in the English version it says '*To define a new converter, select the From format and To format from the drop-down lists, enter the command needed for the conversion, and then press the Add button.*' Trying it out, the *Add* button is activated after selecting something different from either of those menus. Not sure exactly how it works though, you can't create a new converter from LaTeX (pdflatex) To PDF (pdflatex), but as you define the command for the converter yourself, (ctd.)

Comment: (ctd.) that is perhaps not so important, you'll just get the 'wrong' name for your new converter. (Haven't tested this though.)

Comment: And this is the second Thanks, `=)`. Returning to the creation of a new converter, I was used to do it with TeXworks, because it only needed two command-line options and the job was done; so I'm surprised that LyX has not implemented this feature yet...

Comment: @AndreaL. maybe no one has [requested it](http://www.lyx.org/trac)

Comment: This works, thanks! (I also put the --shell-escape in LaTeX(Plain)-to-DVI).

Comment: Do remember that `--shell-exscape` is quite dangerous. Use with extreme care.

Comment: @scottkosty [Just added.](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8898#propertyform), but I'm still "fascinated" by this lack of my supposed-to-be-favourite IDE. (I now begin to understand the dis-approval of egreg for it...).

Comment: @AndreaL. It looks like I misunderstood your question. Now I understand and as mentioned in the ticket, it is possible to add new converters in LyX. However, that it was not clear to you how to do it might be a bug in the UI. Please let us know (new ticket :)) if you have an idea for how to improve it

Comment: @AndreaL. Why is LyX a "supposed-to-be-favourite IDE"? It's liked by some and not by others. It all comes down to preferences. If you want to constantly be writing the LaTeX code, then of course you will not like it because it tries to write the LaTeX code for you. I think there are many good reasons to use LyX. I also think there are many good reasons not to use LyX.

Comment: @scottkosty I guess the point (in this specific case) is to have two different versions of one converter, e.g. LaTeX -> PDF with `pdflatex`, where one has `--shell-escape` enabled, and one does not.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, right. Thanks for the explanation. I believe this is possible but one must define a new file format (e.g. `PDF (shell escape)`) and then the converter will be unique: LaTeX -> PDF (shell escape)

Comment: @scottkosty I was thinking the same, because from the `To Format` menu there can be chosen only un-matched file formats, and I do not know if it's possible to create the `PDF(shell escape)` format...

Comment: @AndreaL. To create the `PDF(shell escape)` go to Tools > Preferences > File Handling > File Formats and click on "new"

Comment: @scottkosty Oh. My. Well... I guess that this so wanted "format files" window has always been under my nose the entire time (I may start to think that I'm actually blind) `=)`.

Comment: @AndreaL. well, the preferences window is kind of cluttered. There are many that I have never experimented with.

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, recently I began to notice some new parameters even after writing my thesis with it (not to mention the hours passed for understanding the document layout...).