# PSTricks at LyX (via pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, lyx, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I'm using LyX (at Windows) and I'm trying to get pdf file output while I have PSTricks code (I put as `\ERT`.
I Try to write at the preamble things like: `\usepackage[off]{auto-pst-pdf}`
 and  `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`, but it still don't compile to pdf file output. (also `ps4pdf` doesn't help...).

Can you tell me how can I do it?

Thank you!

---

Here is the code:

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twocolumn,english,hebrew]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\def\@outputdblcol{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \global \@firstcolumnfalse
    \global \setbox\@leftcolumn \box\@outputbox
  \else
    \global \@firstcolumntrue
    \setbox\@outputbox \vbox {%
      \hb@xt@\textwidth {%
      \kern\textwidth \kern-\columnwidth %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
      \kern-\textwidth %**
      \hfil
      {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
      \hfil
      \kern-\textwidth  %**
      \hb@xt@\columnwidth {%
         \box\@outputbox \hss}%
      \kern-\columnwidth \kern\textwidth %**
    }%
  }%
  \@combinedblfloats
  \@outputpage
  \begingroup
  \@dblfloatplacement
  \@startdblcolumn
  \@whilesw\if@fcolmade \fi
  {\@outputpage
    \@startdblcolumn}%
  \endgroup
  \fi
}
\@mparswitchtrue

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\pscircle(0,0){1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

the problem is the missing optional argument `-shell-escape` for `pdflatex`. You can add it with `Tools->Setup->File->Converter->LaTeX (pdflatex)`

[image]

Then you need only in the preamble

```
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}
```

and, of course, but the PSTricks stuff into the `pspicture` environment:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
\pscircle(0,0){1}
\end{pspicture}
```

However, using `xelatex` instead makes it easier, no need for package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: It's still doesn't work....

Comment: maybe that it doesn't save the option. Reconfigure and  restart LyX and have a look. If the option is not present, then there is a problem with LyX. Under Linux the option is saved in `~/lyx/lyxrc.default` You can edit also this file.

Comment: see also the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144427/programmatically-load-an-image-from-lyx

Comment: Still, id doesn't work...:-(

Comment: Give more information. Is the option set if you open the setuo menu?

Comment: @Hrebert, yes...

Comment: ok, then try `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`. Maybe you have no Perl installed.

Comment: Not, it still doesn't compile......

Comment: At dvi (`ctrl+d` is fine...).

Comment: Before the `shell` it should be `-` or `--`??

Comment: `--shell-escape` or `-shell-escape` makes no difference

Comment: So what can sole the problem? can you have any idea? (If this helps, I writing at Hebrew mode (an Hebrew article).

Comment: post your LyX document for a download then I'll test it.

Comment: How do i post it?

Comment: see my edited answer. The `pspicture` environment is missing.