# Errors after upgrading OS and Lyx

Tags: lyx, minted, xkeyval

I use Lyx everyday. Yesterday I decided to format my computer and install Xubuntu 18.04 (I had Xubuntu 16.04). After installing Lyx I am getting this errors:

[image]

Although the errors, the PDF is properly created so it works. Anyway I would like to get rid of this errors. I have searched in Google with no much luck.

Comment: Just add `--shell-escape` like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144432/120578

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you just have to re-set your preferences in lyx to let it know that you want to run pdflatex with `--shell-escape` flag.

This flag can not be a default feature in open source systems (and general but once more in open source) because a hacker can harm your system. See [here](https://0day.work/hacking-with-latex/).

So, your upgraded version came without that feature enabled and this is why you get the error.

The best practice is to run such codes (with `minted` package or similar that requires this flag) only if the code is yours (or trusted) from command line (adding manually this flag) or using a similar way to enable it (not by default but only when you need it).

For example, to compile a file `main.tex` in your home folder, you have just to
open a terminal and write the command:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape main
```

To see how you can get rid the error (and in the same time let your system be vulnerable when running untrusted LaTeX code) see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144432/120578).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After adding that option when I hit to export PDF I get a warning advertising that it is dangerous and then I get [this](https://image.ibb.co/hKVJ7K/imagen.png) errors. Why do I have to add that flag (which is insecure) to compile the exact same documents I always compiled without that flag before upgrading?

Comment: You can't compile some latex code which containing `minted` package without that flag. Somehow, the warnings was not there in the previous edition (or was disabled) and the flag was running (but you just didn't knew). I don't know if these errors comes from minted (ooor other part of the code).

Comment: It seems that the problem has to do with the parameters I have defined for the code listings. I have [this](https://image.ibb.co/eKx4ge/imagen.png) under "Tools --> Preferences --> Code listings". If I do not introduce any code listing in my document I get those errors. If I introduce any code listing in my document, the errors go away and everything works ok. As you can see in the attached image (in the link) the "Syntax Highlighting Package" is selected to be "Listings" and not "Minted".

Comment: Ok... Then the problem is something new and extra... Please ask a new question with that will contain a MWE we can use and answer.