# Include figure from Hyperlink continuouly on LaTex

Tags: graphics

I try to include a figure from a webpage. But I don't have any idea how to do this. Can anyone tell me how to include a figure using [Gummi]

Comment: 1) Download the image; 2) Include the image. There's no way to include an image *directly*... it has to be downloaded first. Automated, or manual, but that has to happen first.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5433/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Hi Werner, I want to get the image directly from server. Is there any option for that

Comment: @MuthuKumar : have you take a look at the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document ? I think their is some information about what you want to do

Comment: Ya , I already saw that. But in my Gummi, I used that . The image is becomes with full blank. So I want the program from You.

Comment: @MuthuKumar: No. The only way is if you enable `--shell-escape` as part of your compilation and allow an external program to download it before including it. This is covered in the suggest duplicate source [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5433/5764)

Comment: @MuthuKumar Do you want the picture to be loaded at compile time or at viewing time?

Comment: So The image should be download first

Comment: @AlexG I want the picture to be loaded at compile time

Comment: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=15554&sid=26aca1910a034761b7a6160ed423854a

Comment: @Werner -shell-escape is already in that. So I have no idea to include the figure in the Latex of Gummi