# Include the image from hyperlink

Tags: viewers

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \href{http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pachydyptes_ponderosus.jpg}
         {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture}}
    \caption{A reconstruction of New Zealand Giant Penguins (\emph{pachydyptes ponderosus}) by 
      F.~W.~Kuhnert (1865--1926). Click on the image to visit the page on Wikimedia Commons where it 
      was downloaded from.}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the correct code. But it becomes black image. Is there any problem

Comment: Hi daniel, This link is I already tried.

Comment: I have the problem in use graphics package. That is not worked. Butu with demo it is ran,but the image is black. So I want the simple program to run the image from the webpage of hyperlink.

Comment: As described in the linked answer you can't do this with TeX directly. You have to save the picture locally and include this copy.

Comment: The you have posted is not supposed to download the image from the web, it requires that you have already downloaded the image to the same folder as your `.tex` file and named it `picture.jpg`. All the `\href` command does is create a hyperlink to the image on the web. Try the technique in the accepted answer there (with `wget`) to download the image automatically.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. R u have any idea for get the image from the folder continuously by loop control. Please give me the loop for the step

Comment: What do you mean by loop? I can't really say any more than I've done already: [see this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5436/586).

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I want to get iterate from folder. Can you help me

Comment: So you want to get all the images from a folder? A folder on the web, or a local folder? Either way, I cannot help.

Comment: Ok. Thank for your reply. Please help me for this. Do you know any expert in the LaTex. Please mail me for some doubts. I have doubts in Latex. My mail id is muthukumaratyahoo@gmail.com

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is either. I think you need to give a bit more information. By the way, there are experts like Ulrike Fischer who you can pay to help you.

Comment: Apadilam onum avasiyame illa

Comment: @Johannes_B Are you know about this stage. Are you will to chat with me .

Comment: I think there curretnly is a large language gap here. You could try the mailing list of the indian TUG (http://www.tug.org.in/list.html). Maybe language restrictions aren't a matter there.

Comment: K. Are you know anybody's mail id to ask the doubts in the chat.

Comment: I don't even know what the last message is suppposed to mean. I bet the indian group can refer you to a person who can help you without a language barrier.