# How to include an image from a website?

Tags: graphics, wallpaper

I'm using the **wallpaper** package to insert a jpg image in the background of a page. Specifically, I'm doing something like this:

```
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\begin{document}
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{summary-analysis-bg.jpg}
\end{document}
```

The image is in the same folder as the .tex file.

What if I wanted to compile the pdf but, instead of using an image from the same folder, use an image from a web address? The naive approach (replacing the file name/location with some image's web address) doesn't work.

Is there some approach that works?

Comment: Because a web side can be down or be deleted allways copy the wanted image on your own computer. Sure is sure ...

Comment: You could write some kind of harebrained `curl`/`wget` script, but I fail to see why you would bother?

Comment: Mind the copyright issues anyway!

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5433) I guess?

Comment: `bashful`....... (but I agree it is not a great idea)