# Unable to include graphics from Google Drive network file

Tags: includegraphics

I want to include graphics from a Google Drive network file, using the LaTeX Base online LaTeX editor. The command `\includegraphics {https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqbedMUmelhHP0ZnB12MvUIXcyAg1Hix}` fails with the error message

> LaTeX Error: File `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqbedMUmelhHP0ZnB12MvUIXc
> yAg1Hix' not found.

The file exists and is accessible for all to view. The file opens correctly with Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome. The filename is `Etab.jpg`.

How can I make LaTeX Base understand what I want to achieve?

A previous, more general question on this forum on the same topic is yet unanswered.

I am using a free version of the package and therefore not entitled to support from the supplier.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the „LaTeX Base online LaTeX editor“? Do you maybe have a link to that project?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document for including remote files. You will need a direct link to the real image - the Drive link just points to the download page. [LaTeX Base](https://latexbase.com/static/pricing) only supports uploading your own files manually (from your own computer) with the free tier.

Comment: TobiBS: the LaTeX Base online LaTeX editor is available at latexbase.com.

Comment: epR8GaYuh: I thought that LaTeX Base couldn't access files on my computer, since it is an "online" editor. Please show me how I can upload graphics files to LaTeX Base from my computer. The network file I am trying to include is my file and exists on my computer.

Comment: I cannot access files on your computer directly, but you can upload your files to LaTeX Base. Did you try the buttons above the editor? There is the folder icon, clicking on it allows selecting a provider. With the free tier, only the "Local Filesystem" option is unlocked - which you need to upload your local file. Then you should be able to include it as a regular image.

Comment: epR8GaYuh: I pressed the Import icon and selected a provider: local filesystem. There I selected Etab.jpg, my graphics file. LaTeX Base then came back with the error message; "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}". I think it expects a .tex file, not a .jpg file.

Comment: user187802: I inserted \externalfigure[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqbedMUmelhHP0ZnB12MvUIXcyAg1Hix]. LaTeX Base  came back with the following message; "! Undefined control sequence.
l.222 \externalfigure
                     [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqbedMUmelhHP0ZnB12Mv...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

Comment: I tried to use \write18 wget without success. LaTeX Base has an image upload URL interface where I inserted a modified link to my Google Drive graphics. The file was retrieved successfully, but there was no way I could assign a local filename to it for subsequent use in \includegraphics. I have no switched to tne Overleaf online LaTeX editor, which has a nice file upload interface for both local Windows files and network files, AND with the capability to assign a local filename. Now \includegraphics works fine, and I have no further issues with uploading graphics.