# Using Files on the Internet Automatically?

Tags: input

Suppose I want to tabulate file [`WILL5000INDFC.csv`](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=WILL5000INDFC) as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable}
\begin{document}
%https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=WILL5000INDFC
\csvautolongtable{WILL5000INDFC.csv}
\end{document}
```

Can I read it remotely during compiling? Or can I automatically download and include it during compiling?

Comment: Are you using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @TeXnician That doesn't solve the problem, because the `socket` library can't do SSL.

Comment: You can automatically download it at runtime using shell-escape  and `curl` or `wget` (of course this opens security problems).

Comment: Or otherwise maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document, that is about images specifically, but it has a clear example of a `wget` call.