# Can I use an image located on the web specifically in Overleaf?

Tags: graphics, overleaf, external-files, online

This question isn't a duplicate of [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document) but a more specific version of it for Overleaf, since none of the answers given there work on that E.g. the accepted solution (with a real-life example picture)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % includegraphics command is implemented here
\begin{document}

\write18{wget https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png}
\includegraphics{Wikipedia-logo-v2.png}

\end{document}
```

results in

```
File `Wikipedia-logo-v2.png' not found on input line 6.
```

Is there a working solution of this for Overleaf?

Comment: wget is available but I think the docker container that they give you has no external internet access (but you'd need to  check with overleaf support) so you need to download locally and upload (in the free version at least)

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions are best addressed directly to the Overleaf Helpdesk.

Comment: @Mico It's done. No reply yet. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, please direct Overleaf specific questions to Overleaf support. You can get in touch with them here: https://www.overleaf.com/contact (I'm on the support team).

As also mentioned, you have no internet access during the compile process so you can't dynamically download content.

You can load a read-only copy of a file hosted elsewhere using the "from URL" file input option described here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_upload_a_file_using_an_external_URL. While it isn't fetched dynamically at compile time, this option provides a "refresh" button on the file which can be used to get an updated version of the file at any time.

Comment: The Overleaf Support gave the same answer.

Comment: Yup, we're the same people :)